# How to replace folder/filenames in bulk in Magento

Tags: html, magento, e-commerce

I've just inherited a Magento site from a web development agency. I've migrated it across and it all seems to be working fine, aside from some images are missing.
I've worked out that it's because the previous developers have uploaded files into folders with case-sensitive names. So for example, inside the media/catalog/product/ folder, they have two folders name /s/ and /S/
Their system obviously allows these case-sensitive file names. Mine does not!

What has happened is that, as the files were copied across to my server, the system has combined /s/ and /S/ into one folder, and given it the uppercase name (/S/). The problem is then that Magento tried to reference some images at /s/ and of course it can't find them, as on my server that folder does not exist.

I have lots of folders where this has happened, amounting to thousands of product images.

Does anyone know how to get around this? Is it possible to change the server settings to accept case-sensitive folder and file names? Or do I need to go through the database and do some sort of REGEX to replace all lowercase folder names with uppercase folder names?
In the latter case, does anyone know how to do that and which database tables are involved?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First correction to a misconception --> *I've worked out that it's because the previous developers have uploaded files into folders with case-sensitive names.*

They didn't do this, this is how Magento stores files that it has processed and moved to its media directories.

Magento expects to be run on an operating system that fully understands and uses case on file names. *nix and Mac OS-X use this natively, Windows understands it in a sort of Compatibility Mode. Your major issue comes about with what you use as a transfer method between the different OS's that corrupts it.

The easiest way is to ask them for a zipped tarball and then use Windows 7-zip to dearchive it on your Windows system. There's too much work involved to mess around with correcting this after the fact, use a transfer method from their server to yours that preserves case.